# Visual Studio 2015/2017 local NuGet feed HTTP 403

Tags: visual-studio, iis, nuget-package, http-status-code-403, nuget-server

We've created a local NuGet feed with [Nuget.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/). It is a simple ASP.NET application that is hosted on an IIS web server that is part of our local company network.

The url of the feed looks like this:

```
https://abc.company.com/packages/nuget
```

The ISS authentication is enabled as followed:

[image]

The .NET authrization looks like this:

[image]
If I call the above mentioned feed url with Postman or Fiddler I get the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="https://abc.company.com/packages/nuget/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
    <workspace>
        <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
        <collection href="Packages">
            <atom:title>Packages</atom:title>
        </collection>
    </workspace>
</service>
```

If I now add the URL in the Visual Studio NuGet package sources:
[image]
and then choose the newly created package source the following screen appears where I enter my domain credentials (domain\user), but nothing happens:

[image]

As described before, when I access the site with any Browser (IE, Chrome, Edge) I don't have to enter my credentials and Fiddler/Postman do also not require any credentials.

On the VS PackageManager Output I get the following error message:

```
[Local] The V2 feed at 'https://abc.company.com/packages/nuget/Search()?$filter=IsAbsoluteLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net462'&includePrerelease=true&$skip=0&$top=26' returned an unexpected status code '403 Forbidden ( The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator.  )'.
```

When I call this URL with a browser I don't get any errors.

What is wrong in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by our company proxy, that was also taken into account when opening internal sites. So I've added the following environment variable:

```
NO_PROXY
```

as value I've added the company internal domain:

```
NO_PROXY = "abc.company.com"
```

No it works locally and on our build agents.

Comment: where did you add that variable ? In the nuget server, on your machine, inside your Visual Studio  ?

Comment: @Poutrathor: I've added it on my machine as environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have to disabled `SSL Require` in IIS `SSL Settings`

Comment: where did you do that?

Comment: @RafaelPimenta open IIS, click on your site on left menu, then choose `SSL Settings`, you will check "SSL Require" checkbox, disable it